# How to change the colours of a dataset using mapbox

Tags: node.js, mapbox

So i'm trying to allow for users of my map to be able to select a radio button, and if the value of that radio button matches a name in the projectObj, i want that circle to turn red. Below i'm showing how i create the radio buttons (hbs) and projectGrab function. I know i can change the colours of the layers since i can move the map.SetPaintProperty call to within my for loop and have it turn every circle red.

I know the if statement works as well, it can find a match but for some reason whatever way i try i can't change the colour.

I've added the layer within a for loop because I couldn't think of how to differentiate between each location.

Radio creation. Funder names is just an array of the names i've garnered from a sql query. Some of which do match the funder_titles

```
  {{#each funder_names}}

  <label for={{this}}>
  <input type="radio" name="country1" class="checkboxSelect" value="{{this}}" onClick="projectsGrab(this.value)" >{{this}}
  </label>
  {{/each}}
```

Adding the layer

```
for (i = 0; i < projectsObj.features.length; i++) {

        map.addLayer({
          id: 'project_locations' + projectsObj.features[i].geometry.coordinates,
          type: 'circle',

          maxzoom: zoomthreshold,
          // Add a GeoJSON source containing place coordinates and information.
          source: {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: projectsObj
          },
          paint: {
            "circle-radius": 15,
            "circle-color": "#FFFFFF",
            "circle-stroke-width": 2,
            "circle-stroke-color": "#FFFFFF"
          }

        })

      }
```

highlighter

```
 function projectsGrab(value) {



      for (i = 0; i < projectsObj.features.length; i++) {


        if (projectsObj.features[i].properties.funder_title === value) {

          projectHighlighter(projectsObj.features[i].geometry.coordinates)

        }

      }





    }

    function projectHighlighter(geo) {
      console.log('fired')


      map.setPaintProperty('project_locations' + geo, 'circle-color', '#FF0000')



    }
```

ProjectObj

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -5.943629,
                    54.559632
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "18a Newforge Lane, Belfast, Belfast, BT95NU, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "funder_title": "Engineering"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    36.81667,
                    -1.28333
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "Nairobi, Nairobi, Kenya",
            "properties": {
                "funder_title": "Arts and Hu"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.97,
                    56.464
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "Dundee, Dundee City, Scotland, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "funder_title": "Chief Scien"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick comment and then a recommended change in your approach.

#### Comment

Your for loop appears to be adding one style ***for each*** feature and giving them ids based on their order in your object. From your description it sounds like your goal is to only create one style layer, so you will likely need to modify your approach there to avoid any future confusion.

#### Recommended approach

If you want to have a conditional style based on the radio-botton's state. You can achieve this using[feature state](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfeaturestate) instead.

Here's an example of what this looks like in action: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️